# Establish two way Connection between node.js and C# windows application

Tags: c#, node.js

I want to establish two way communication between the C# Windows application and Node.Js.
Currently I am calling node.js functionality using below code.

```
using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "node.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommand;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.Start();
```

node.Js have a database operation. I want confirmation from user at some point. How to do this ?

I have checked using named piped. but not able to understand how it will work.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing to stdin and stderr, and reading from stdout? You're already redirecting stdin and stdout.

Comment: Hi @DiplomacyNotWar, I have created event but not getting anything on event. everytimes it return null values,    process.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;     static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }

Comment: Hi @DiplomacyNotWar , my node.js is separate application.  I just used return statement. Do I need to do additional in to that application ?

Comment: `return` (both in C# and in Javascript) means that you're returning some value to the calling method (or that you're leaving the method and returning to the calling method in the case of `return;` since it doesn't return any value). Returning a value isn't the same as writing to the application's output. I'd expect you would have to use `console.log` in Javascript to write to stdout.

Comment: You can add a Browser to your Form (like CefSharp), navigate to your WebPage and have a bidirectional communication through the browser. It has some extra of work but you gain lot of control in the comunication process.

Comment: Use named pipes or a network based solution.

Comment: Greatly appreciate for the help.  For now I have done with stdout and stdin. Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar for the direction.  This may be not perfect way but my aim is only read the some data and ask confirmation to the end user.